# How to fill a line graph when automating the plot froma data frame

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I have the following code

```
fname = 'mse-collectl-xxxxxxx-20130505-170328.cpu-mem.clean'
cpu_mem_data = read_csv(fname, sep=' ', index_col=1, parse_dates=True)

cpumain = cpu_mem_data[['CPU-User%','CPU-Nice%','CPU-Sys%','CPU-Wait%']]
cpumain.plot(grid='on')
cpumain[:10]
plt.show()
```

Example of data
             CPU-User%  CPU-Nice%   CPU-Sys%    CPU-Wait%
Time
2013-11-25 17:04:10     2   0           5           1
2013-11-25 17:04:20     0   0           5           0
2013-11-25 17:04:30     1   0           4           0
2013-11-25 17:04:40     1   0           4           0

Standard line plot is perfect but 
I am struggling with getting a filled in line plot because I am passing the data frame objects to plot and I don't directly control the axis.

Only my 3rd day with Python and Pandas so consider me uninformed.
I did a lot of research and I see how to use the file_between but that requires specifying the Axis

Many thanks

Laurenc

Answer (score 1):

The pandas `plot` methods return an axis object, so, for example, you can do

```
ax = cpumain.plot()
```

and then proceed to manipulate `ax`.

The matplotlib functions like `plt.plot()` don't return axes, but pandas' plotting methods uniformly do.

For your particular use case, it might be easiest to just pass columns from the DataFrame to `plt.fill_between`.